# MASON Get Moore Neighbors

Tags: java, agent-based-modeling, mason-abm

I am making a simulation with MASON. I have a SparseGrid2D object which I populated as follows in my main simulation class:

```
protonLayer = new SparseGrid2D(HEIGHT, WIDTH);

        MersenneTwisterFast g = new MersenneTwisterFast();

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_PROTONS; i++) {

            // Creating the proton
            Proton p = new Proton(new Int2D(g.nextInt(WIDTH), g.nextInt(HEIGHT)), this);

            // Adding it to schedule
            schedule.scheduleRepeating(p);

        }
```

And in my steppable class I then call:

```
Bag neigh = s.protonLayer.getMooreNeighbors(location.getX(), location.getY(), 1, 1, new Bag(), new IntBag(), new IntBag());
```

However, for some reason neight.size() keeps returning one instead of returning all neighboring cells. I thought that getMooreNeighbors excluded empty neighboring cells, so I added:

```
// Moore locations doesn't return empty grids .-.
        for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {

            for(int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {

                protonLayer.setObjectLocation(new String("a"), i, j);

            }


        }
```

To my main class to try and get around this, but it hasn't worked even though every cell is now populated by at least one object!

Any thoughts?

Full version of code:

ProtonTest.java

```
package protontest;

import ec.util.MersenneTwisterFast;
import sim.engine.SimState;
import sim.field.grid.SparseGrid2D;
import sim.util.Int2D;

public class ProtonTest extends SimState{

    public SparseGrid2D protonLayer;
    public final int HEIGHT = 100;
    public final int WIDTH = 100;
    public final int NUM_PROTONS = 1;

    public ProtonTest(long seed) {

        super(seed);

    }

    public void start() {

        protonLayer = new SparseGrid2D(HEIGHT, WIDTH);

        MersenneTwisterFast g = new MersenneTwisterFast();

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_PROTONS; i++) {

            // Creating the proton
            Proton p = new Proton(new Int2D(g.nextInt(WIDTH), g.nextInt(HEIGHT)), this);

            // Adding it to schedule
            schedule.scheduleRepeating(p);

        }

        // Moore locations doesn't return empty grids .-.
        for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {

            for(int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {

                protonLayer.setObjectLocation(new String("a"), i, j);

            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        doLoop(ProtonTest.class, args);
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

Proton.java

```
package protontest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.lowagie.text.pdf.hyphenation.TernaryTree.Iterator;

import ec.util.MersenneTwisterFast;
import sim.engine.SimState;
import sim.engine.Steppable;
import sim.util.Bag;
import sim.util.Int2D;
import sim.util.IntBag;

public class Proton implements Steppable {

    public Int2D location;

    // Building the proton and adding it to a random location
    public Proton(SimState state) {

        ProtonTest s  = (ProtonTest) state;

        MersenneTwisterFast g = new MersenneTwisterFast();

        // Random location
        int xloc = g.nextInt(s.WIDTH);
        int yloc = g.nextInt(s.HEIGHT);

        location = new Int2D(xloc, yloc);

        // Add object
        s.protonLayer.setObjectLocation(this, location);


    }

    // Building the proton and setting it at a given location
    public Proton(Int2D location, SimState state) {

        this.location = location;

        ProtonTest s = (ProtonTest) state;

        s.protonLayer.setObjectLocation(this, location);


    }

    // Same as constructor above, but takes two ints instead of an Int2D object
    public Proton(int xloc, int yloc, SimState state) {

        this(new Int2D(xloc, yloc), state);

    }

    // Stepping about
    public void step(SimState state) {

        ProtonTest s = (ProtonTest) state;

        MersenneTwisterFast g = new MersenneTwisterFast();

        // First thing first, does the proton stabilize independently?

        int p = 100; // Proton will stabilize (hence be removed from the simulation) with probability of 1/p

        int rand = g.nextInt(p);

        // If rand = 0 then it met the 1/p probability fo being removed. 
        if(rand == 0) {

            s.protonLayer.remove(this);
            return;

        }

        // Get moore neighbors 
        Bag neigh = s.protonLayer.getMooreNeighbors(location.getX(), location.getY(), 1, 1, new Bag(), new IntBag(), new IntBag());



        // Now we make a map that maps a location to an int. The int will be increased for every proton found at such location in the neighborhood.
        Map<Int2D, Integer> m = new HashMap<Int2D, Integer>();
        ArrayList<Int2D> a = new ArrayList<Int2D>();


        // Looping through neighbors
        for(Object o : neigh) {

            // The "Proton Neighbor"
            Proton pN = (Proton) o;

            // Location of current element
            Int2D thisLocation = pN.location;

            if(!m.containsKey(location)) {

                m.put(location, 1);
                // There probably is a better way of iterating through maps
                a.add(location);

            } else {

                // Everybody loves casting
                int newCounter = ((int) m.get(location)) + 1;

                m.put(location, (Integer) newCounter);


            }           

        }

        // Wait, we also want to know how many protons in the current cell
        int pAtLocation = s.protonLayer.numObjectsAtLocationOfObject(this);

        // Get minimum value from map (ie location where there are fewer protons in neighborhood)

        int currentMin = pAtLocation;
        Int2D location = this.location;

        // For each neighbor
        for(Int2D loc : a) {

            // Get number of protons
            int currentM = (int) m.get(loc);

            // If there are fewer then the proton will migrate there, unless a better locationis found
            if(currentM <= currentMin) {

                currentMin = currentM;

                location = loc;


            }


        }

        // Move the proton to the new location aaaaaand done
        s.protonLayer.setObjectLocation(this, location);
        System.out.println(neigh.size());


    }

}
```

Comment: Have your tried other modes: Grid2D.BOUNDED?

Answer (score 0):

```js
   IntBag xNeighbors = new IntBag(8);
        IntBag yNeighbors = new IntBag(8);

        // Get moore neighbors
 
        Bag neigh = s.protonLayer.getMooreNeighbors(location.getX(), location.getY(), 1, Grid2D.BOUNDED, new Bag(), xNeighbors, yNeighbors );

        for (int i = 0; i < xNeighbors.numObjs; i++) {
            System.out.print(" x = " + xNeighbors.get(i));
            System.out.println(" : y = " + yNeighbors.get(i));}
```

I added the above to your code to check the coordinates that are output for the moore neighborhood and they are the same one. Hence you are restricting the test to a single cell and thus getting only that cell's return.